# problem with this code for traditional numberline

Tags: bidi, poetry

I want to typeset poem verses that are numberedline.
use with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Yas}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{1cm}
\newcount\LineNumber \newcount\templinenumber
\newdimen\linenumberskip \linenumberskip=-0.75em
\chardef\linestep=1
\def\poemlinenumber{%
\advance\LineNumber1
\templinenumber=\LineNumber
\computelinenumber
}
\def\computelinenumber{%
\ifnum\templinenumber>\linestep
    \advance\templinenumber-\linestep
    \expandafter\computelinenumber
    \else
    \ifnum\templinenumber=\linestep
    \leavevmode\rlap{\kern\linenumberskip\footnotesize\the\LineNumber}%
    \fi
    \fi
   }
   \newenvironment{numberedtraditionalpoem}
   {\everypar{\poemlinenumber}
    \begin{traditionalpoem}}
   {\end{traditionalpoem}}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{numberedtraditionalpoem}
  ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید\\
   ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید
 \end{numberedtraditionalpoem}
 \end{document}
```

The problem is the text between the poem when. text like poem Numberd.
please help.

Comment: If I understand your question is "how to resume numbering of poem for another  `numberedtraditionalpoem` environment" , (text between the  two environments) ?

Comment: no i want use one environment. but tex between `numberedtraditionalpoem` so that tex unnumbring.

Answer (score 1):

[A similar question](http://qa.parsilatex.com/12478) was asked last night on the ParsiLaTeX forum.

This is almost a rough translation (from Persian to English) of what the user asked (I think both users are the same noting the common name `ata`):

> How do I put some ordinary text (not poem) inside the `numberedtraditionalpoem` such that it is not numbered?

The solution was to define the command `\interpoemtext` similar to the `\intertext` command of `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Yas}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{1cm}
\newcount\LineNumber \newcount\templinenumber
\newdimen\linenumberskip \linenumberskip=-0.75em
\chardef\linestep=1
\def\poemlinenumber{%
    \advance\LineNumber1
    \templinenumber=\LineNumber
    \computelinenumber
}
\def\computelinenumber{%
    \ifnum\templinenumber>\linestep
    \advance\templinenumber-\linestep
    \expandafter\computelinenumber
    \else
    \ifnum\templinenumber=\linestep
    \leavevmode\rlap{\kern\linenumberskip\footnotesize\the\LineNumber}%
    \fi
    \fi
}
\newenvironment{numberedtraditionalpoem}
{\everypar{\poemlinenumber}
    \begin{traditionalpoem}}
{\end{traditionalpoem}}
\makeatletter
\newbox\interpoemtext@box
\newcommand{\interpoemtext}{\PackageError{bidipoem}{Invalid use of \string\interpoemtext}\@eha}
\def\interpoemtext@{%
  \def\interpoemtext##1{%
    \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
    \noalign{%
      \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
      \setbox\interpoemtext@box\vbox{\normalbaselines
      \everypar{}
       \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
        \ifdim\linewidth=\columnwidth
        \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
        \fi
        \noindent##1\par}%
        \unvbox\interpoemtext@box%
      \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
    }%
}}
\bidi@preto{\@traditionalpoem}{\interpoemtext@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{numberedtraditionalpoem}
ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید\\
\interpoemtext{%
ین یک متن آزمایشی است.این یک متن آزمایشی است.این یک متن آزمایشی است.این یک متن آزمایشی است.%
}
ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید
\end{numberedtraditionalpoem}

\end{document}
```

This will produce the following output:

[image]

which I guess is what the question is asking.

Comment: Yes Mr vafa Khalighi. I am same user parsilatex forum. In that froum I ask again exactly the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VafaKhalighi. here another approach which consist of using two environments  `numberedtraditionalpoem` and replace the definition of `\LineNumber` counter  with `\newcounter{LineNumber}`, in this case value of counter can be used outside `numberedtraditionalpoem` environment.

To reset counter just add  `\setcounter{LineNumber}{0}`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\usepackage{bidipoem}

\renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{1cm}
\newcounter{LineNumber} \newcount\templinenumber
\newdimen\linenumberskip \linenumberskip=-0.75em
\chardef\linestep=1
\def\poemlinenumber{%
\addtocounter{LineNumber}{1}
\templinenumber=\value{LineNumber}
\computelinenumber
}
\def\computelinenumber{%
\ifnum\templinenumber>\linestep
    \advance\templinenumber-\linestep
    \expandafter\computelinenumber
    \else
    \ifnum\templinenumber=\linestep
    \leavevmode\rlap{\kern\linenumberskip\footnotesize\theLineNumber}%
    \fi
    \fi
   }
   \newenvironment{numberedtraditionalpoem}
   {\everypar{\poemlinenumber}
    \begin{traditionalpoem}}
   {\end{traditionalpoem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{numberedtraditionalpoem}
  ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید\\
   ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید
\end{numberedtraditionalpoem}

ین یک متن آزمایشی است.این یک متن آزمایشی است.این یک متن آزمایشی است.این یک متن آزمایشی است.

\begin{numberedtraditionalpoem}
  ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید\\
   ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید
\end{numberedtraditionalpoem} 

\setcounter{LineNumber}{0} 
\bigskip

\begin{numberedtraditionalpoem}
  ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید\\
   ازدست و زبان که برآید & کزعهده ی شکرش بدرآید
\end{numberedtraditionalpoem} 

\end{document}
```

[image]